# Eclipse gives "invalid resource directory name" when I add a non-resource PNG file to my Android project

Tags: android, eclipse

I want to associate a PNG file with my Android project in Eclipse, but I don't want to actually publish it - it's just a higher-resolution version of the various icon.png files that I used to generate the icon.png files. But wherever I put this PNG file, I get the error "invalid resource directory name". Where am I supposed to put it? I really don't want to put it outside of the project folder, because that would disassociate it from the project!

Comment: R-Click the file and Resource Configuration -> Exclude Resource?

Comment: I don't see any "Resource Configuration" menu option...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `_workspace` folder to your resource folder and put it there.

Comment: Thanks! Is /res/_workspace a magic folder name in Android projects, or does the underscore tell Eclipse to ignore it?

Comment: You are welcome! The underscore will tell Eclipse to ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

What are you using it for? You could put it in your drawable folder and name it icon_ginormous.png. That way you can reference it using your resources.

Comment: I'm not using it; I just wanted to store it. You say I can reference it in resources? So the icon.png files don't actually need to be the required resolution?

Comment: Theoretically you could only have one set of icons for all resolutions. It will be ugly but you can do it. Android will display them, it just won't be pretty. By putting them in the -hdxpi, -mdpi, etc. folders you are telling android to pick them depending on the device resolution. If you put it just your drawable/ folder though you can reference it using R.drawable.icon_huge and depending on your layout android may or may not resize it.